# Modify path directory - "The config file `C:/Program Files/Git/` was not found"

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the flutter_native_splash package and there is a part of the documentation where I can create a separate .yaml, so I have to put the command

> `$ dart run flutter_native_splash:create --path=path/my/.yaml`

But for example when I put `--path=/` I get as response

> ```
> $ dart run flutter_native_splash:create --path=/ Building package
> executable... (2.1s) Built flutter_native_splash:create. The config
> file `C:/Program Files/Git/` was not found.
> ```

Where is it configured that this is a path? Where can it be changed?